# SOLR search not returning results

Tags: content-search, solr

I am new to SOLR search.

I have created all cores and index and SOLR UI is showing that documens have been indexed. I have copied the working core folder and renamed it and also updated in proprieties.json file and schema name and then just added in the UI.

[image]

here is my sitecore index configuration, just a standard index configuration, nothing special.

[image]

here is the code I am using in Sitecore 8 to query search index.

I am getting 0 records from index.

[image]

Sitecore index from control panel also showing documents have been index but I can't see why I get 0 results.

[image]

Querying the index through UI also shows that keyword exists in some documents. If I change index name to "sitecore_web_index" I get some results, the only difference between these 2 index is the index id, all other configurations are same.

here is the SOLR query log If I search for "branch"

path=/select params={q=breadtext_t:(*branch*)&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)&rows=1000&version=2.2} hits=38 status=0 QTime=3

path=/select params={q=breadtext_t:(*branch*)&fq=_indexname:(RBSM_web_index)&rows=1000&version=2.2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1

Sitecore Query log

2092 12:53:16 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=_name:(breadtext)&rows=1&fq=_templatename:("Template field")&fq=_indexname:(RBSM_web_index)
2092 12:53:16 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=_name:(breadtext)&rows=1&fq=_templatename:("Template field")&fq=_indexname:(RBSM_web_index)
2092 12:53:16 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=breadtext_t:(*branch*)&rows=1000&fq=_indexname:(RBSM_web_index)

and for working index

1180 12:50:19 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=_name:(breadtext)&rows=1&fq=_templatename:("Template field")&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)
1180 12:50:19 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=_name:(breadtext)&rows=1&fq=_templatename:("Template field")&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)
1180 12:50:19 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=breadtext_t:(*branch*)&rows=1000&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)

I have also noticed an error entry in the logs

1876941 ERROR (qtp7980742-19 - /solr/RBSM_web_index/admin/file/?file=admin-extra.html&_=1511403018192) [   x:RBSM_web_index] o.a.s.h.a.ShowFileRequestHandler Can not find: admin-extra.html [C:\Bitnami\solr-5.5.0-1\apache-solr\solr\RBSM_web_index\conf\admin-extra.html]

Is this ignorable?

**Update:** for the time being I am using sitecore_web_index which is working fine except it is returning some items from path sitecre\shell etc, although root is configured as sitecore/content/home

[image]

Comment: Could you run your query, then open Search.log.txt and see which query was build and sent to the Solr? Share it with us.

Comment: As already mentioned by Artsem, could you provide the raw query which is being sent to Solr.

Comment: So you are not specifying any templates or fields it looks like. Do you have <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields> in your file? I did not see it, but maybe I missed it.

Comment: @RReilley defaultSolrIndexConfiguration has <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate the solr scheme?

Comment: @Ali silly question, but did you try to restart solr and your sitecore instance? do you have any result when you remove the `.Where` clause?

Comment: yes restarted solr jetty windows service many times and also removed where clause but no results.

Comment: You can post your soution as answer then it is easier to find it in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem was in index name case, when I changed index name all lower case letters, it worked. so

RBSM_web_index should be rbsm_web_index

Comment: True. My case i was used in index configuration, core name is "Custom_SolrDemo_index". No search results but after change it to "custom_solrdemo_index" i got search results.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. After adjusting the configuration files from lucene to solr the index generation works fine. Also I get results if I use the solr admin web search, but the GetResults() method in the code (same as in thread owner post) did not return any results. The log files inform me that the query was successfully sent to Solr (query is logged in the solr.log file).

I changed the index configuration to the default one and removed the whole where clause - but I still did not get any results.

The used versions are SC 8.2 and Solr 5.1.0.

Any helpful feedback would be appriciated :)

Comment: I have fixed the issue, check my updates.

Comment: Hi Ali, your fix works for me too. After I renamed the index in lower case I got results too :)